# I want to reinstall ubuntu as to remove the full disk encryption

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, encryption

Please skip to *now the problem is..* part if you aren't a frequent reader :)

I successfully installed ubuntu 17.10 64bit today. However, I checked the option for full disk encryption during the process. Now whenever I boot my system, a screen asking for encryption password pops up. The issue is kinda common and I have researched a bit about it. People showed up methods to remove the screen and what not. **BUT**

In my case, its a fresh install so I can easily re install the whole OS. I don't have any settings or files to backup so im totally okay with reinstalling..

**Now the problem is..**

I want to reinstall with a DVD. When I press f2,f3,f12 on startup, normal boot stops and a new screen comes up. It has got three options but none of them start a new boot from DVD for a fresh install. The first option starts a normal ubuntu boot, the second option leads to 4 new options.. These options again lead to more options including grub terminal and all. The third options leads to BIOS or UEFI to be precise..

Somebody help me overcome this problem.

*I'm new to Linux and to this forum. This is my first post. so please be patient with me :)*

THANKS!!

Comment: Boot into the BIOS and set the optical disk CD/DVD as first boot device. Boot from install disk and reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried entering your BIOS and selecting to boot from your DVD drive? And/or changing the the boot order?

(Sorry if that seems obvious, it's not clear from your post if you've tried that yet. :)

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what was causing the issue. I thought its the GRUB causing issue.. sorry that's insane :P
I had to switch to legacy support from UEFI in boot and push CD/DVD up in order.. 
Thanks mate!! :)